# How to init langage index in a Prestashop Module?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to create a new page in a Prestashop Module, so I created a controller and a view. Unfortunatly I got this error and I don't found a solution.
This my error : [image]

This is my controller:

```php
<?php

require_once _PS_MODULE_DIR_.'opartdevis/models/OpartQuotation.php';

class OpartDevisAskTypeClientModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public $auth = true;
    public $guestAllowed = true;
    

    public function init()
    {
        $this->display_column_left = false;
        $this->display_column_right = false;
        parent::init();
    }

    public function setMedia($isNewTheme = false)
    {
        parent::setMedia();

            $this->registerStylesheet(
                'opartdevis-style',
                'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/views/css/opartdevis.css'
            );
            $this->registerJavascript(
                'opartdevis-front',
                'modules/'.$this->module->name.'/views/js/front.js'
            );
            $this->registerJavascript(
                'opartdevis-tools',
                'js/tools.js'
            );
    }

    public function initContent() {
        $this->setTemplate('module:opartdevis/views/templates/front/ps17/asktype.tpl');
    }


    public function postProcess()
    {
        $type = Tools::getValue('typeClient');

       /**  return Tools::redirect(
           * $this->context->link->getModuleLink(
            *    'opartdevis',
             *   'createquotation',
              *  array(
               *     'create'=>true,
                *    'typeClient'=> $type
                *)
            *)
        *);*/

    }
}
```

This is my view:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name="page_content"}
    {capture name=path}Ask your client type{/capture}
    <h1>Quel type d'utilisateur etes vous ?</h1>

        <form action="{$link->getModuleLink('opartdevis', 'askTypeClient')|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="opartDevisForm">
            <p>Quel type d'utilisateur êtes vous ?</p>

            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="clientType" name="askType" value="clientType"
                        checked>
                <label for="clientType">Client</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="providerType" name="askType" value="providerType">
                <label for="providerType">Provider</label>
            </div>

            <p class="cart_navigation">
                <a href="{$link->getPageLink('my-account', true)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" class="btn btn-default button button-small">
                    <span><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> {l s='Back to Your Account' mod='opartdevis'}</span>
                </a>
                <button type="submit" name="submitQuotation" id="submitQuotation" class="button btn btn-primary button-medium"><span>Submit</span></button>
            </p>
        </form>
{/block}
```

Could you help me please ?

I based the structure of my code on another controller and it works without any line about language index.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function initContent() {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'language' => $this->context->language->id,
        ));
        $this->setTemplate('module:opartdevis/views/templates/front/ps17/asktype.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Thx for your help but it still doesn't work :/ With the same error

Comment: Exactly the same? Error is on layout-both-columns. It can be before your module load. Anyway in my answer it would be language object, not language id. If you disable your module, does PS work properly?